# Webpack: How to expose a class constructor to browser’s global namespace

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm new to webpack and can't figure out how to expose a class constructor to the browser’s global namespace. For example, how do I configure webpack so that the code below prints “hello world” in the console? I've tried using `exports-loader`, `expose-loader`, and `script-loader` without success.

**main.js**

```
class MyClass {
  print() {
    console.log('hello world');
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
    <script>
      myClass = new MyClass;
      myClass.print();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either:

**a) Expose your function (class) explicitly:**

*main.js*

```
class MyClass {
  print() {
    console.log('hello world');
  }
}

window.MyClass = MyClass;
```

Then you can call your constructor from global object by referencing `MyClass` directly.

**b) Configure webpack to expose your exports in a global object as follows:**

*webpack.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
    output: {
        library: 'someName',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        globalObject: 'this'
    }
}
```

Then you can call your constructor by referencing exported function (class) in a global variable configured as `library` option in above config file. In this example `someName.MyClass`. For this to work you must export the function in main.js file, as shown below.

*main.js*

```
export class MyClass {
    print() {
        console.log('hello world');
    }
}
```

Refer to [webpack output configuration](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output) for more specifics.

Comment: I can only get the forced `window` assignment to work (example (a)). Declaring a library (example (b)) just creates an empty object by that name in the browser. It does not have any of the exported classes attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

[Current webpack API](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/) uses `library` object (or string, in that case it is treated as `name`) to expose the namespace to the global scope. You can rely on defaults and simply do something like

```
import path from 'path';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname),
  entry: './src/index.js',  //path to a file that exports things you need
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'webpack-numbers.js',
    library: 'MyAwesomeLib'
  },
};
```

and you will find the `./src/index.js` exported contents at `window.MyAwesomeLib`. You can be more specific (see [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrary)):

```
module.exports = {
  // …
  output: {
    library: {
      name: 'MyLibrary',
      type: 'window', //umd, global, ...
    },
  },
};
```

but then you might experience empty objects if not configured properly. Relying on default setup works nicely.